# How to transform array of arrays into one array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to transform one array of arrays by doing a specific transform, like the following example:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]  => [14, 15, 24, 25, 34, 35];
```

Note, the first element of the first array is concatenated to each element of the second array to form a new array, and so on with the second element, third... etc

Comment: Note really. Another exemple of what i want to achieve:
`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]  => [14, 15, 24, 25, 34, 35];`

Comment: I don't think you mean to concatenate arrays, you mean a specific transformation, I advice you to correct your question and its description

Answer (score 0):

Use array.concat and for loop

```
let arrays =   [
  ["a1","b1","c1"],
  ["a2","b2","c2"],
  ["a1","b1","c1"],
  ["a1","b1","c1"],
]
let arr = [];
arrays.forEach(array =>{
    arr = arr.concat(array)
})

console.log(arr)
```